# capture webcam stream and send it over network using DirectShow.net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, video-streaming, directshow, video-capture

I m working on a video conference project in vs2010 with c#. I m able to capture the snaps from web cam in picture box with the help of Directshownet samples available on SouceForge.But i can't find any proper solution for capturing the audio/video stream directly from web cam using Directshownet. If anybody know about this problem's solution, pls give me ur advise .

Waitng for ur response ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add `SampleGrabber` to your DShow filter graph and use it to capture video frames.

Some links: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407288%28VS.85%29.aspx), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SampleGrabber.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

libvlc bindings might could do it for you

Answer (score 0):

If you use GraphEdit, from windows SDK, you should be able to access audio capture devices and add that and then do what you want with it. From there you can go into DirectShow or DirectShowNet and add these filters easily to mimic what you have in Graph Edit